# XNA Draw doesn't draw last image in the Draw Routine

Tags: c#, button, menu, xna, draw

I have a main menu that doesn't draw the last two buttons in the Draw loop..  I can take out the top one and it won't draw the last one (But draws the one above it).  Can anyone help?

```
if (gameState == GameState.TitleScreen)
        {
            this.graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 800;
            this.graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 511;
            this.graphics.ApplyChanges();

            //Draw the Logo
            spriteBatch.Draw(Logo, LogoPosition, Color.White);

            //Draw the PlayButton
            spriteBatch.Draw(PlayButton, PlayButtonPosition, Color.White);

            //Draw the Options Button
            spriteBatch.Draw(OptionsButton, OptionsButtonPosition, Color.White);

            //Draw the Credits Button
            spriteBatch.Draw(CreditsButton, CreditsButtonPosition, Color.White);

            //Draw the Exit Button
            spriteBatch.Draw(ExitButton, ExitButtonPosition, Color.White);

            //Draw the Website Button
            spriteBatch.Draw(WebsiteButton, WebsiteButtonPosition, Color.White);

            //Draw Background
            TreeBackground.Draw(spriteBatch);
            TreeBackground2.Draw(spriteBatch);
        }
```

The positions of these buttons are included here:

```
//Positions
        PlayButtonPosition = new Vector2((GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2) - 50, 200);
        OptionsButtonPosition = new Vector2((GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2) - 50, 250);
        CreditsButtonPosition = new Vector2((GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2) - 50, 300);
        ExitButtonPosition = new Vector2((GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2) - 50, 350);
        WebsiteButtonPosition = new Vector2((GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2) - -400, 0);
```

Comment: Did you do a basic check of your buttons' position? `ExitButtonPosition` and `WebsiteButtonPosition`? Are they within your visible surface? Try to comment another button's `Draw` and put one the problematic button in its place... does it work?

Comment: @SuperOli I have tried that, it isn't a problem with the positions, it happens with other buttons if I put them at the bottom too

Comment: It sounds as though they have the same position as other buttons, changing the graphic height isn't something that should be done every frame either, that should be done in the initialize

Comment: If its a different size fine, it still doesn't need to be done every frame, do it once when you change to that screen

Comment: Sorry, I don't seem to be able to put them on new lines?!

Comment: @dannmat - Edit your question to include that information